# Заполнение карты

Tags: java

```
for(int i =0; i< str.length;i++){
    count =1;                            //содержит количество повторений
    for(int j=i+1;j<str.length;j++){
        if(str[i].equals(str[j])){
            count++;
        }
    }

//проверка есть ли в карте такой элемент, если нет то положить в карту  элемент и количество повторений

    Set<Entry<String,Integer>> en = rez.entrySet(){
        for(Entry<String,Integer>e:en){
            if(count>1&&(!rez.containsKey(e.getKey()))){ //если в карте не содержится ключа положить
                    rez.put(str[i], count);  
            }  
        }
```

В результате карта пуста. Почему карта не заполняется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы итерируете по карте и проверяете что вхождение в карте не существует.

```
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> en = rez.entrySet(){

        for(Entry<String,Integer>e:en){

            if(count>1&&(!rez.containsKey(e.getKey()))){ //если в карте не содержится ключа положить

                rez.put(str[i], count);  
            }  
                        }
```

Comment: а как проверить существует ли такой ключ в карте?

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa, зачем вы вообще итерируете по карте? проверяйте есть ли символ в карте, если нет то добавляйте